# WIF using SAML 2 protocol / Federate AD FS 2.0 with CAS

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, wif, adfs2.0

I'am are trying to implement a Web SSO with claim based identity using WIF and AD FS 2.0 right now. Right now I have a existing ASP.Net application which delegates authentification to the AD FS 2.0 server and trust issued security tokens. That works just fine.

However, in the organization there is an existing JA-SIG Central Authentication Service (CAS) server which supports the SAML 2 protocol. I would like to replace AD FS 2.0 with the existing CAS service.

In my understanding WIF uses WS-Federation, which is like a container around a SAML token. Is it possible to use the plain SAML 2 protocol and it's bindings (redirect or POST)? If that is not possible (as I guess), a second alternative might be to use federate identity and federate AD FS 2.0 with CAS. Is that possible? There is little to no information about that on the web.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I came up with the following issues. CAS 3.x supports SAML 1.1 tokens and the SAML 1.1 protocol including Web SSO. There is support for SAML 1.1/2.0 tokens in ADFS 2.0. However, only the SAML 2.0 protocol is supported. That means no out of the box federation between CAS and ADFS 2.0 is possible.

We are researching [OpenSSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSO) as an alternative now, which provides support for all necessary protocols including WS-Federation for attaching WIF clients.

Answer (score 1):

Access control Service v2 (ACS v2) may be an option. It supports both SAML1.1 and 2.0 as well in addition to other ones like simple web token (SWT) etc. It then allows to translate tokens from the source system to the relying party format..
https://portal.appfabriclabs.com/Default.aspx